# Computing whether a set of polynomials cuts out a projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, computational-geometry, computer-algebra

I have a set of multivariate polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$, and I want to compute whether they cut out a projective variety, i.e. whether the radical of the ideal $I$ that they generate is homogeneous. My first idea is to compute $\sqrt{I}$ and then check whether the homogeneous components of each generator of $\sqrt{I}$ are in $\sqrt{I}$. I have verified in Macaulay2 that $I$ itself is not homogeneous. It appears that Macaulay2 will not compute $\sqrt{I}$ in a reasonable amount of time, so I am posting here to ask for other ideas (or an efficient implementation).

Here are the nuts and bolts of my ideal $I$. Let's arrange 16 variables into a $4 \times 4$ matrix

$$X=
\begin{bmatrix} A && B \\ C && D\end{bmatrix},
$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices of indeterminates. The ideal $I$ is generated by $96$ polynomials. The first $48$ polynomials are the $3 \times 3$ minors of $X$, the $3 \times 3$ minors of
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A^T && B^T \\ C^T && D^T\end{bmatrix}.
$$

and the $3 \times 3$ minors of

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \vec{A} && \vec{B} && \vec{C} && \vec{D}\end{bmatrix},
$$

where $\vec{A}$, etc. is the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ viewed as a $4 \times 1$ column vector. Note that this indeed gives $3*{4 \choose 3}^2=48$ polynomials (which generate a homogeneous radical ideal). The other 48 polynomials are the same, with $X$ replaced by

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0&&1&&1&&0\\1&&0&&0&&0\\1&&0&&0&&0\\0&&0&&0&&0\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} A && B \\ C && D\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Note: This has been [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3700987/748775) from Math.SE.

Comment: One might be able to guess one point say $X_0$ (in the affine space) satisfying the equations. Then one can check if $\lambda X_0$ satisfy the equations for every $\lambda$ in the field. (Since the equations are inhomogeneous, perhaps there is a $\lambda$ such that $\lambda X_0$ is not a solution.)

Comment: Your first set of $48$ polynomials depends on $X$ and two other matrices, so it isn't clear from your current description how to change these other two matrices to get the other $48$ polynomials. Do you mean to say replace A by A + the corresponding block, etc?

Comment: @tim Yes, you understand correctly.